# How to get the blogger posts feed and to incorporate it to an HTML5 page?

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I'm trying to get the data from the  blogger and to put it on a HTML page.
The code HTML code is the following:

```
<section class="colorlib-blog" data-section="blog">
                <div class="colorlib-narrow-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-md-pull-3 animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft">
                            <span class="heading-meta">Read</span>
                            <h2 class="colorlib-heading">Recent Blog</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft">
                            <div class="blog-entry">
                                <a href="blog.html" class="blog-img"><img src="images/blog-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="HTML5 Bootstrap Template by colorlib.com"></a>
                                <div class="desc">
                                    <span><small>April 14, 2018 </small> | <small> Web Design </small> | <small> <i class="icon-bubble3"></i> 4</small></span>
                                    <h3><a href="blog.html">Renovating National Gallery</a></h3>
                                    <p>Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInRight">
                            <div class="blog-entry">
                                <a href="blog.html" class="blog-img"><img src="images/blog-2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="HTML5 Bootstrap Template by colorlib.com"></a>
                                <div class="desc">
                                    <span><small>April 14, 2018 </small> | <small> Web Design </small> | <small> <i class="icon-bubble3"></i> 4</small></span>
                                    <h3><a href="blog.html">Wordpress for a Beginner</a></h3>
                                    <p>Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft">
                            <div class="blog-entry">
                                <a href="blog.html" class="blog-img"><img src="images/blog-3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="HTML5 Bootstrap Template by colorlib.com"></a>
                                <div class="desc">
                                    <span><small>April 14, 2018 </small> | <small> Inspiration </small> | <small> <i class="icon-bubble3"></i> 4</small></span>
                                    <h3><a href="blog.html">Make website from scratch</a></h3>
                                    <p>Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 animate-box">
                            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-load-more">Load more <i class="icon-reload"></i></a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

which generates the folloing part of the page:

[image]

I want to replace this data from this code with a blogger content ... so I'm getting the link for the blogger.

I have to get the images thumbnail of the post the name of the post the link of the posts and a description of the post to put on this html code.

The code to get the data from the blogger is the folloing:

```
<html>
<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
function getPosts(json) {
    var list = [];
    var data = json.feed.entry;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var img = data[i].media$thumbnail ? "<img src'" + data[i].media$thumbnail.$t + "'>" : "";
        list.push("<div><a href='"+ data[i].link.pop().href + "'>" + img + data[i].title.$t + "</a></div>");
    }
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = list.join('');

}
</script>

<script src="https://www.blogger.com/feeds/614640065733671379/posts/default?alt=json&max-results=3&callback=getPosts"></script>
</html>
```

But it gives just the links of the posts as this:

```
teste3
teste 2
Teste
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you need to allow full feed in order to get the third party image and post content

Go to **Settings** > **Others** > **Site feed** > **Allow Blog Feed** and select **Full** then **Save Settings**

Then try this: (require full feed)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#demo {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.feed-post {
 padding: 10px;
 width: 30%;
    word-break: break-word;
}
.feed-post a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.feed-post img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 object-fit: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="demo"></div>

<script>
function getPosts(json) {
    var list = [];
    var data = json.feed.entry;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        
        var title = "<h3>" + data[i].title.$t + "</h3>";
        var link = data[i].link.pop().href;
        var summary = "<p>" + data[i].content.$t.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "").substr(0, 120) + "</p>";
        if (data[i].media$thumbnail) {
         var img = "<img src='" + data[i].media$thumbnail.url + "'>";
        } else {
         var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data[i].content.$t, "text/html");
         var imgtag = doc.querySelector('img');
         if (imgtag) {
          var img = "<img src='" + imgtag.src + "'>";
         } else {
          var img = "";
         }
         
        }

        list.push("<div class='feed-post'><a href='"+ link + "'>" + img + title + "</a>" + summary + "</div>");
    }
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = list.join('');

}
</script>

<script src="https://www.blogger.com/feeds/614640065733671379/posts/default?alt=json&max-results=3&callback=getPosts"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please allow the full feed as explained in my answer!

Comment: I got this message "The feed specified by https://angelribeirocomp.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/full is not enabled"

Comment: Try now I updated my answer. I used `querySelectorAll` instaead of `querySelector` :)

Comment: Also, you can control the summary length by changing the char number in `substr(0, 120)`

Comment: how to I get the date and the author of the posts?

Comment: Ok, you can get post date from `data[i].published.$t.substr(0, 10)` and author from `data[i].author.name.$t`.